# How change the order of words in a CSV file using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file like this

```
Abc  12
bcd 123
bsd 45
bfs 34
```

I need to change this file to
number first form.

```
12 abc
 123 bcd
45  bsd
 34 dfs
```

In this form 
What I have done.

```
import csv
with open('name.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    file = open("names.txt", "w")
    for row in reader:
        for j in range(0 ,len(row)):
            file.write(row[j])


file.close()
```

The current output

```
12
123
34
```

Expected output

```
12 abc
 123 bcd
45  bsd
 34 dfs
```

Any clues?

Comment: What is the problem with what you currently have? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected output (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
import csv

with open('name.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    with open("names.txt", "w") as o:
        writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow((row[1], row[0]))
```

*Edit:*

If you can use `awk`, this will be much simpler:

```
$ awk -F '\t' 'OFS="\t" {print $2, $1}' < name.csv
```

- `-F '\t'`: fields in the input are separated by tabs
- `OFS="\t"`: fields in the ouput shall be separated by tabs, too
- `{print $2, $1}`: for each line in the input, print the second and the first field

Answer (score 0):

You can read each line from the file (using **readlines()**) and use the **strip()** (To remove end of line characters)  and the **split()** function (To remove white spaces and separate out entities)  with default arguments to convert each line into a temporary array:

For example

```
FileHandle = open("file.txt", 'r')
LinesInFile = FileHandle.readlines()

for line in LinesInFile:
    Arr = line.strip().split() #This will give Arr = ["Abc", "12"] for line = "Abc 12"
```

Following this you can use the list **pop()** method to get the last element and print that to a file, eventually reversing the order and putting the number before the word.

For example

```
Num = Arr.pop() #this will get you 12
Wrd = Arr.pop() #this will get you "Abc"
```

You can run the above logic in a loop (as shown above in the code snippet) to generate a new file that has the required structure by printing Num and Wrd in the same loop into the file.

Comment: The [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) does exist. Remember, Python comes with batteries included.

Comment: Okay. Didn't know about it (Never used it). Of course this answer wasn't pythonic but solves the problem :)